# Add and subtract two row values together based on second column

Tags: sql, oracle

| Total | worktype |
| --- | --- |
| 900 | planes |
| 500 | cars |
| 780 | bikes |
| 100 | variation |

I have data set up like this I want to return the data but add the 100 from variation to the cars worktype giving me 600 cars  and subtract variation 100 from the planes giving me 800 planes so output would be

| Total | worktype |
| --- | --- |
| 800 | planes |
| 600 | cars |
| 780 | bikes |
| 100 | variation |

Comment: What's your logic from your question?

Comment: this is a representation of the result of a large query which has given me these I have a variation figure that I need to add to the cars figure and subtract from the planes figure then display the ammended totals thats it Im stumped on best way to acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select worktype,
       (case when worktype = 'cars'
             then total + sum(case when worktype = 'variation' then total else 0 end) over ()
             when worktype = 'planes'
             then total - sum(case when worktype = 'variation' then total else 0 end) over ()
             else total
        end) as total
from t;
```

If there is only one row with `'variation'`, you can also use a `join`:

```
select t.worktype,
       (case when t.worktype = 'cars'
             then t.total + tv.total
             when t.worktype = 'planes'
             then t.total - tv.total 
             else t.total
        end) as total
from t join
     t tv
     on tv.worktype = 'variation'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your query I just can give you a tip.

do like:

```
SELECT (PLANES - VARIATION) AS PLANES,
    (CARS + VARIATION) AS CARS,
    BIKES,
    VARIATION
FROM (<YOUR MEGA QUERY WHICH MUST TO HAS [PLANES, CARS, BIKES, VARIATION]>)
```

Probably you can put it into the query without nesting, but I do not see anything and I prefer to be ensure in the answer.